# AJAX Timeout aborts request when file is being uploaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML form with a file input field that uploads the selected file using AJAX. It also features a progress bar.

I tested it and had a few occasions when the request kept hanging with no response. I want to prevent this from happening and add a 10 second timeout that aborts the request if the file has not started uploading within that time.

I obviously tried using the built in AJAX timeout option but that fires even if the file is being uploaded. AJAX timeout is only cleared once the server has responded and that only happens once the file has finished uploading.

**Is there a way to have a timeout on the AJAX request that stops counting down when the file has started uploading?**

Comment: you can just code your own timeout on open(): xhr.myTimeout=setTimeout(xhr.abort.bind(xhr), 10000);
 and then in your progress event handler: clearTimeout(xhr.myTimeout);

Comment: @dandavis AJAX does not report progress only state changes to javascript. and the uploading state is the sending request state so the change wont happened untill the script has completed the upload so if the upload is taking longer than your time limit the timeout will still occure

Answer (score 0):

No not using AJAX i think the best thing to do would be to find what causes it to hang occasionally the other option would be to build a Socket Client in Java and use a Java Applet to do the upload for you but then you would need to know Java or find some one who could do it for you.

but a timeout is exactly what it say's on the tin a Timeout it does not matter whats happening a timeout ending is a end of allowed time to run.

Comment: What about adding the timeout to the PHP code?
The timeout would abort the PHP script and return error if the file upload has not started in, let's say, 10 seconds. So is there a way to add a PHP timeout and clear that timeout once file upload has started?

Comment: The problem you have is sending the timeout! if you set the php timeout the same problem will occur. if you can find out where it hangs you will be able to better handle it the problem is with php the upload is sent from the browser with the request so php does not start until the file has been sent to the server using `BASE64` you could try not using AJAX and using WebSockets to do the file transfer but this would limit you to html5 browsers only with a flash fall back